# android tablet to serial port communication using delphi

Tags: android, delphi, printing, serial-port

I am trying to send data to a impact printer that is embedded to a tablet.
This is what the unit looks like [link here](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/76-mm-impact-printer-and-IC_60349601593.html). I've already tried the Comport for android from winsoft and I am not making any progress in printing on the impact printer and I used the sample code there from FMXexpress [here](http://www.fmxexpress.com/access-the-com-port-on-android-with-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-component/)

Here is my code:

```
unit uSample;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, Winsoft.Android.ComPort,
  FMX.Edit, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    AComPort1: TAComPort;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Memo1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
      Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     AComPort1.Active := False;
     AComPort1.DeviceName := Edit1.Text;
     AComPort1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
     AComPort1.WriteByte(Ord(KeyChar));
     ShowMessage('Down');
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var Text: string;
begin

end;

end.
```

The Memo1KeyDown part just shows the message "Down" when it should be sending data to printer and printing some data.

Thank you in advance for yor help.

Comment: I suspect that the comport you are trying to send on is actually the device's external output comport and not an internal one. Have you seen the inside and how the embedded printer is connected to the tablet?

Comment: No I haven't seen the inside.

Comment: Is there any test software from device provider? Does it print? Should printing command data contain some specific sequences like CR, LF etc?

Comment: Actually there is. There is a printer app when the user click on a button on that app the printer will print a test page of 3 lines. And that is my problem, how can I connect to the printer using delphi because I'm thinking that that app was programmed using other android IDEs. If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Any documentation? Do you know right port name/number, baud rate, parity and other parameters? Are there any android serial port monitors/sniffers like Russinovich's `portmon`?

Comment: No documentations are included when I got this unit. All I know is the printer is in ttyS3 in dev. I got that port because I tried using the Serial Port API Sample from this link: https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-serialport-api/. Then I tried changing the port name in AComPort component in delphi to dev/ttyS3 but still I cannot make the printer work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in contact with a person who seems to be supplying the device. They asked that the person who acquired the device request from them the SDK which will allow hopefully more info.